# I am trying to send multiple title and multiple files into database using laravel but i am getting error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send  multiple title and multiple files into database using laravel but i am getting error please help me how can i resolve this issue ? thanks.

**getting error**

```
Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile as array
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
  

        foreach ($request->title as $key => $value) {

            $audiodetail = new AudioDetail;
            $extension = Str::random(40) . $request->file('audio_file_upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $audiodetail->audio_file = Storage::disk('audiofile')->putFileAs('', $request->audio_file_upload[$key], $extension);
            $audiodetail->title = $value;
            $audiodetail->audio_id = $event->id;
            $audiodetail->save();
        }

        return redirect()->route('events');
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the $request->all() value?

Comment: please check it  dd($request->all())        https://ibb.co/7nDCmsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` and `audio_file_upload`  both are different array. So you need to combine both :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $data = array_combine($request->title, $request->audio_file_upload);
     foreach ($data as $value) {
         $audiodetail = new AudioDetail;
         $extension = Str::random(40) . $value['audio_file_upload']->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $audiodetail->audio_file = Storage::disk('audiofile')->putFileAs('', $value['audio_file_upload'], '.' . $extension);
         $audiodetail->title = $value['title'];
         $audiodetail->audio_id = $event->id;
         $audiodetail->save();
     }
     return redirect()->route('events');
}
```

Comment: You will get an error, because I really dont know about `event->id`

Comment: it's working but the image is uploading to the database like this gXYljZU1IyR5xBag7EYRJpqsJOdg6WHMhNsEZ1Dejpeg  but it should be like this gXYljZU1IyR5xBag7EYRJpqsJOdg6WHMhNsEZ1De.jpeg with dot extesion

Comment: then change it to `->putFileAs('', $value, '.' . $extension);`

Comment: OK sir but it's working perfectly but I have one question that title is key after combined array if I submit same  title name I think it will be wrong because due to same title name the first title name will be inserted in database whereas second title name will not be inserted. Please give me best solution thanks

Comment: I think that title should not be key .

Comment: if `title` and `audio_file_upload` hold the same quantity of data, then it will work only with array_combine() so you dont lost any data then

Comment: its OK but now I am trying submit  same title name with files but it's showing the first title name in db not second